# R graph in function of different modalities

Tags: r, plot

I would like create a lot of graph in function of different modalities of two variables.

For example, we have this table "data":

```
values=round(runif(20, min=15, max=40),digits=2)
years=rep(c('2002':'2005'),5)
letters=rep(c("a","b","c","d"),5)

data=data.frame(values,
                years,
                letters,
                row.names = NULL)
data$years=as.factor(data$years)
```

I would like create a different plots of values in function of the years and the letters.
I tried with a for loop but that not function:

```
years.graph=c('2002','2003','2004','2005')
letters.graph=c('a','b','c','d')

par(mfrow=c(4,4))
for (i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
    with(data[data$years==years.graph[i] & data$letters==letters.graph[j],],plot(values))
  }
}
```

Are there someone for help me?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start here

```
data=data.frame(values,
                years,
                letters,
                row.names = NULL)
data$years=as.factor(data$years)
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
data


for (i in levels(data$letters)){
      da <- subset(data, letters == i)
      plot(da$years, da$values, type = "n")
}
```

and you get

[image]